# Are thse Hemianthus callitrichoides aka Dwarf Baby Tears?

Tags: aquatic-plants

I was sold these plants as Hemianthus callitrichoides. But I am now not so sure they are. I would like to know if they are or not. And if they are not, what they may be.

[image: Hemianthus Callitrichoides?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does look like *Hemianthus* but the plant is dying so it's hard to say, it could also be a monte carlo plant.

I recommend reading [this guide](http://www.plantedtank.net/articles/Basics-to-starting-a-Planted-Tank/4/)

Substrate

> Substrates such as Flourite and Eco-Complete provide a long lasting supply of Fe to the plants through the roots. While each of these products can be costly per bag to buy, it provides you the best start to growing nice plants. I personally have used both with great success. Plants "will" grow in your average aquarium gravel but the size of the gravel is very important. It needs to be a finer grain in size and it will also need to be fertilized to provide the nutrients to the plants.

Lighting:

> There are a few ways to do this and the most common way is via "Compact Flourescent Lighting". They are available in many sizes and can be used in combination with each other to get the amount of watts needed to grow your planted aquarium.

What do they need?

> Micronutrients: these are available to us through our tap water and commercially sold liquid fertilizers such as Flourish, Kent, Tropica MasterGro, etc. Start off by dosing per the bottle instructions. With time and plant growth you may find the need to up your dosages slightly. Excessive dosing will promote algae growth.
>
> Macronutrients (nitrogen, phosphorus, potassium).
>
> Nitrates supplied using potassium nitrate (KNO<sub>3</sub>). Target is 5 - 10 ppm.
>
> Phosphates supplied using monopotassium sulfate or Fleet Enema. Target is 0.5 - 1 ppm.
>
> Potassium supplied using potassium sulfate (K<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub>) or potassium chloride (salt substitute like No-Salt). Target is 20 ppm.

What about CO<sub>2</sub>?

> The addition of CO<sub>2</sub> is very important to achieve lush growth of your plants, especially when your tank lighting is anywhere above 2 <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub> WPG. In low light tanks where the demand is small for your plants CO<sub>2</sub> addition is generally not needed, but as you increase the strength of your lights, you are in turn increasing the demand for more carbon to get the most out of your plants.

Comment: Thank you. They were planted only a week ago in a 43" (W) x 30" (H) x 18" (D) - 100.5 gallon tank in ADA Amazonia substrate with ADA Super 4 and are lit by Zetlight QMAVEN 6400 for about 14hrs everyday. I got CO2 in there as well. I am thinking they are rotting probably because they were planted newly and they'll recover once they get to their aquatic form (the store that sold them to me had them cultivated in a dry start environment). Or am I kidding myself?

Comment: No, your not kidding yourself. It's indeed possible that they need to get used to the new environment  and will recover (as long as they receive enough fertilizer, Co2 and light). Just give it some more time.